# Checkpoint VPN Linux command line (CLI) client

Tags: linux, command-line, vpn, remote-access, checkpoint-endpoint

Is there an official/third party **command line** client for the checkpoint vpn for Linux?

[It seems](https://serverfault.com/questions/90275/checkpoint-vpn-linux-client) that there are a few GUI options, but I can't find a client for a headless machine.

Comment: The serverfault question you  point to states that Checkpoint vpn is actually a Cisco  vpn, and that vpnc should work with it. If so, this man page http://linux.die.net/man/8/vpnc will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### SSL VPN - Check Point's client

The only Check Point's currently supported VPN client for Linux is **SSL Network Extender** (SNX). As of 2019-07-15 it officially supports these Linux distributions ([sk65210](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk65210)):

- Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 16.10, 17.04
- openSUSE 11.4, 12.2
- Fedora 15, 16, 18
- RHEL 6.1, 7.3, 7.4

SNX has a CLI (command `snx`) and according to the knowledge base article [sk65484](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk65484) it does not need X11, just some X11 libraries. SNX needs a Mobile Access Software Blade license to work.

### IPsec VPN - 3rd party clients

Check Point also supports IPsec VPN and L2TP for client to site VPNs. There are multiple 3rd party VPN clients which are able to work with the Check Point Security Gateway. You can use for example one from the SWAN family (FreeS/WAN, Openswan, strongSwan, Libreswan).

See also [sk67820 - Check Point Remote Access Solutions](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk67820).

Comment: CheckPoint supports indeed IPsec, however a big *if*, it as to be configured by the FW admin. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450131/vpn-ssl-network-extender-in-firefox/709258 and https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn